# Как настроить reCAPTCHA для формы с AJAX запросом?

Tags: php, ajax, recaptcha

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Есть HTML форма обратной связи с ajax запросом. Не могу прикрутить к ней reCAPTCHA. Без ajax все работает нормально (Форма отправляет письмо только в случае валидации каптчи), а вот с ajax не получается, она просто отправляется без каптчи

**Ajax запрос**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#feedback-form").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send.php",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        $(this).find("input").val("");

        $("#feedback-form").trigger("reset");
        document.getElementById('results' ).style.display = 'block';
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

**PHP обработчик**

```
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        exit('Empty');
    }

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';

    $recaptcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $secret = 'мой_секретный_ключ';
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $url_data = $url.'?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$recaptcha.'&remoteip='. $ip;

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $res = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $res = json_decode($res);

    if($res->success) {
        echo 'YES';
    }
    else {
        exit('Error');
    }
}

    if((isset($_POST['name'])&&$_POST['name']!="")
                         &&(isset($_POST['email'])&&$_POST['email']!="")
                         &&(isset($_POST['message'])&&$_POST['message']!="")) {

        $to = "почта";

        $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
        $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
        $message = "Имя: $name \nEmail: $email \nСообщение: $message";

        $pagetitle = "Новое сообщение";
        mail($to, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $email");
}
```

Comment: Попробуй процесс отправки вставить вот в это условие if($res->success) {
        echo 'YES';
    }

Comment: Да, так работает, спасибо (на саму почту сообщение приходит только в случае проверки капчи). А вот как сделать валидацию в ajax до отправки к обработчику? Чтобы в случае, если каптча пропущена, то просит ввести её.

Comment: По сути,я так понимаю у Вас это уже реализовано ,просто необходимо поработать с условием else если капча не пройдена. Попробуйте  поэкспериментировать с echo,затем уже в js принимать ответ от сервера и работать с ним

Comment: Да вот пробую, но пока что-то не выходит :(

Comment: @Vladislav В мозиле через консоль посмотрите для начала, какие данные уходят методом `post` с помощью `ajax`. Присутствует ли там `g-recaptcha-response` со значением? Вопрос у Вас простой, помочь могу без проблем! Вот вчера только помог решить вопрос по этой же капче. [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676102/recaptcha-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B5-magnific-popup/676622#676622) на stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

Можно получить ключ с помощью grecaptcha.getResponse();

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#feedback-form").submit(function() {

    var _formData = $(this).serialize();
    _formData['g-recaptcha-response'] = grecaptcha.getResponse();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send.php",
        data: _formData
    }).done(function() {
        $(this).find("input").val("");

        $("#feedback-form").trigger("reset");
        document.getElementById('results' ).style.display = 'block';
    });
    return false;
});
```