# reCAPTCHA не работает во всплывающем окне magnific popup

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, recaptcha

Здравствуйте!
Может кто уже сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Имеется ссылка, по клику на которую открывается всплывающее окно magnific popup,  тип запроса — ajax. В подключаемом виде находится `div` с reCAPTCHA от Google, но капча не отображается, лишь только `div` тот же попадает, который требуется добавить от настроек Google по умолчанию со своим ключом (`data-sitekey`), и то его не видно (скрыт).

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="*************"></div>
```

Может кто подскажет, как это можно решить?

Например, на сайте Касперского во всплывающем окне эта капча отлично работает.

## Обновление:

**1) Я пишу между тегами head:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var onloadCallback = function() {
      grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
         'sitekey' : '*****************'            
      });
   };
</script>
```

**2) Затем при открывании окна magnific popup в подключаемом виде следующий код:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">console.log($("#html_element"));
   if ($("#html_element").length > 0) {
      $(".fieldset").append('<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer><\/script>');
   }else { 
      console.log('Такого элемента нет');
   }
</script>
```

Код первого пункта соответствует коду в документации Google по настройке капчи. По пункту 2, кусочек кода — `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>` — как указано в документации Google по настройке капчи.

**3) В процессе открытия всплывающего окна, выполняется php код, исходя из определенного ответа, когда — `$rowlog=1` — `div` показывается:**

```
<?php if($rowlog):?><div id="html_element"></div><?php endif;?>
```

Капча отображается отлично, работоспособность, правда, её не проверял ещё.

**4) Но, когда `$rowlog=0` — `div` соответственно не отображается при открывании, далее выполняется вход на сайт с помощью `ajax`, если получен определенный ответ от сервера с помощью `ajax`, то с помощью `jqury` я добавляю этот `div`:**

```
if(result.captcha === 'yes'){                                          
   $(".yes").fadeIn(500).before('<div id="html_element"></div>');                                             
                                                  
}
```

Добавляется `div` отлично, но `$("#html_element").length > 0` уже не работает. Как-то можно это исправить?

Подсмотрел на одном сайте, у них капча тоже появляется точно также, как я описал.
Но у них пункт 1 и 2 находится в теге head и код пункта 1 и 2 следующий:

```
<script>
    window.captchaOnLoadCallback = function() {
       if (window.UI.captcha) {
            window.UI.captcha.ready('******************');
       } else {
            console.warn('............');
       }
  };
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=ru&amp;onload=captchaOnLoadCallback&amp;render=explicit" defer></script>
```

Comment: Так как ajax - конечно не будет работать, ведь html еще нет. Попробуйте рендерить капчу после запроса, но здесь надо учесть, что если апи капчи грузится асинхронно, то может не успеть подгрузиться. А если капча только в модальном окне, то можно вообще тогда грузить апи вместе с запросом

Comment: @Сергей Мирошник Спасибо. Но, как это реализовать я так и не понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В подключаемом виде для всплывающего окна magnific popup напишите следующее в между тегами `<form></form>`:

```
<div id="captcha-yes" class="hidden">                   
     <div class="field captcha">
         <div id="captcha_widget"></div><!--В данный div будет добавлена reCAPTCHA после открытия окна magnific popup-->
     </div>
     <!--По примеру из документации Google-->
     <script type="text/javascript">
       //Объявляем переменную
       var widgetId1;
       var verifyCallback = function(response) {
          //При успешной активации reCAPTCHA, удаляем элемент с содержанием ошибки, появившийся при неудачной попытке при проверке reCAPTCHA с помощью ajax (ответ пришедший от сервера), с этим думаю проблем не возникнет
          $('#captcha-yes').find('.error').remove();       
       };
       //Из документации Google
       var onloadCallback = function() {
         widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render('captcha_widget', {
           'sitekey' : 'your_site_key',
           'callback' : verifyCallback         
         });            
       };
     </script>
     <!--Перезагружаем captcha при неудачной попытке-->
     <script>
       function reloadRecaptcha(){   
         grecaptcha.reset(widgetId1);
       }
     </script>
     <!--Из документации Google-->
     <script async defer src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit'></script>
</div>
```

По-умолчанию для `div` c `id="captcha-yes"` установлен класс `hidden` со значением display: none;

Пример для неудачного ответа от сервера:

```
if(result.error){
   //При каждой повторной ошибке, удаляем старую, чтобы ошибки не дублировались
   $("#captcha-yes").remove();
   //Добавляем div с ошибкой в начало перед reCAPTCHA
   $("#captcha-yes").prepend('<div class="error">Пожалуйста, подтвердите,
 что Вы не робот</div>'); 
   //Пример по Вашему 4 пункту в обновлении вопроса
   if(result.captcha === 'yes'){ 
      //При ошибке удаляем класс hidden для отображения капчи                                     
      $('#captcha-yes').closest('div').removeClass('hidden');
      //Перезагружаем reCAPTCHA
      reloadRecaptcha(); 
    }
}
```

[Более подробно в документации на официальном сайте.](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api)

Для примера, когда только открываете окно и значение переменной `$rowlog=1`:

```
 <div id="captcha-yes" class="<?php if(!$rowlog):?>hidden<?php endif;?>">
       ...дублировать не буду...
 </div>
```

Условием `<?php if(!$rowlog):?>hidden<?php endif;?>` проверяем, если переменная `$rowlog=0`, то класс `hidden` отображаем, reCAPTCHA скрыта, когда `$rowlog=1` условие не сработает и reCAPTCHA будет отображена во всплывающем окне при открытии.

Будут вопросы, пишите:)

Comment: Супер! Спасибо огромное! Всё как надо, всё отлично отработало:))) УРА!!!

Answer (score 2):

На сколько я знаю гугловые апи - у всех есть два метода инициализации: автоматически и в ручную. Вы пытаетесь использовать автоматический метод, который подразумевает наличие необходимого HTML на странице. Скорее всего (это так, пальцем в небо), у вас есть код на странице, который подключает саму каптчу:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
```

Он срабатывает на текущий HTML и создает глобальный объект `Recaptcha` или `grecaptcha` (нужно поискать в консоли). Для нового HTML вам необходимо запустить инициализацию каптчи еще раз:

```
 Recaptcha.create("your_public_key",
    "element_id",
    {
      theme: "red",
      callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
    }
  );
```

или

```
grecaptcha.render('element_id', {
    sitekey: recaptchaSiteKey,
    callback: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Все зависит от версии API, которое вы используете.

Comment: Спасибо!:) Сейчас попробую разобраться, плюс изучаю сижу документацию. А в element_id указывать id блока куда добавляется капча?

Comment: да) Но, опять же зависит от версии, может подойдет HTML-элемент, выбранный любым селектором