# ReCaptcha в форму

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, recaptcha

Подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь добавить капчу в форму отправки данных на e-mail. Саму капчу понять как добавить не трудно, а вот чтоб срабатывала как полагается не могу понять как. Читал туториал, смотрел статьи, но у меня не работает. Серверную обработку не могу понять, т.к не знаю пхп, для отправки формы использую готовый скрипт. Возможно смогли бы помочь, показав что куда вставить для успешной валидации? Сгенерированный ключ вставлен в форме
Код HTML формы, AJAX отправки и PHP прилагается.

Форма:

```
<form action="/" class="form" method="post">

                    <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="Blabla">
                    <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="some@email.com">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Контактные данные пользователя">
                    <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

                    <div class="input-group">

                        <input id="name" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Имя и фамилия" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">

                        <input id="email" type="text" name="E-mail" pattern="^([a-z0-9_-]+\.)*[a-z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">

                        <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Контактный телефон">
                    </div>





                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit-button" value="Отправить">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdxczcUAAAAAKsbbef_VQgblw-khfd-S0RCL0Vq" style=""></div>


                </form>
```

AJAX:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

//E-mail Ajax Send
$(".form").submit(function() { //Change
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php", //Change
        data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Благодарим за проявленный интерес к нашей продукции.");
        $('.cityAddress').removeClass('active');
                $('.form-block').removeClass('active');
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Done Functions
            th.trigger("reset");
        }, 1000);
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

PHP скрипт для отправки формы:

```
<?php
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {
    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);
    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {
    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);
    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}
$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";
function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;
mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

Comment: А что получает сервер? Какая ошибка? Я бы в Аяксе не писал ***th.serialize()*** а на прямую форму бы сериализовал. Плюс НЕпонятно что за скрипт у тебя капчи??. И как его ты принимаешь на стороне  PHP.  По умолчанию .serialize() нужно принимать в массив по атрибуту name. Не вижу  что бы ты его принял так.

Comment: @dpi, я удалил всю обработку капчи, потому что она не работает, сейчас добавлю и отредактирую еще раз, может так будет проще понять

Comment: могу дать код капчи тупо код. Который передаешь в сесии. и на стороне сервера сверяешь введенное в поле и  то что нужно было ввести. Все норм работает.

Comment: @dpi было бы здорово, спасибо

Comment: @dpi я добавил обработку в пхп как сказано тут https://xn--d1acnqm.xn--j1amh/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC-recaptcha-%D0%BE%D1%82-google-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82

но отправка все равно осуществляется и без проверки капчи и с ней, то есть пользователь может проигнорировать её и ничего не случится
я так понял, что мне необходимо проверять в AJAX'е..?

Comment: Да нужно проверять то тчо там приходит с помощью аякса и при различных вариантах или пропускать или возвращать в форму юзера.
это вот эта функция в PHP json_encode(),  а в JS success (function(){тут твоя логика с сообщением что тут печалька})

Comment: То что ты далл ссылку там же все написанно что нжно делать. А еще бы посоветовал самому сходить в гугл и почитать как там что происходит.  Я так понял у тебя неполучилось зайти на гитхаб и скчать класс ог гугла и сделать проверку? вот же ссылка на гитхаб скачал этот файл с классами и сделал что там хочет от тебя тот сайт  с описанием https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/1.0.0/php/recaptchalib.php

Comment: recaptchalib.php я добавил, тут прикол в том, что даже без проверки капчи все равно уходит эмейл. добавил в аякс еще как тут в ответе реккомендуют (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491939/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-recaptcha-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC ) и все равно уходит, но на эмейле вдобавок отображается capta-response

Comment: @dpi сделал все точь в точь как на том сайте, что сюда кинул, работать то оно работает, но форма, повторюсь, отправляется и без проверки капчи

Comment: А как ты думаешь что за беда у тебя?? В каком месте происходит сбой?  Ты же проверяешь на заполнение капчи в JS?? перед тем как послать форму Я вижу что нет. Ты полюбому отправляешь форму. http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81

Comment: то что у тебя в done(function(){что то ты тут делаешь}). Запихни перед отправкой в sucess :(function(){ вствьть сюда. }) На стороне сервера ты должен отправить результат провеки капчи вот такой вот функцией echo json_encode(); И уже с помощью этого пройдет проверка. правильно.

Comment: ***И последнее а то я устал реально.*** Смотри ты говоришь что сделал так как на том сайте проверку формы. А где это вообще у тебя в твоем проверщике формы отображается?  не ту не подключения скаченного от гугла файла. Зачем проверять и гет и пост масив когда у тебя с пмощью аякса отправляется ПОСТОМ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы решал эту задачу вот так И с удовольствием посмотрел на ваше решение. Вот функция Капчи)

Это PHP

---

```
<?php
 session_start();
function captcha()
{
 $chars = 'abdefhiknrstyzABDEFGHKNQRSTYZ0123456789';
$generate_string = '';
$length = rand(3, 7);

for ($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {
    $i = rand(0, 38);
    $generate_string .= $chars{$i};
 }
return $generate_string;
 }
```

---

На странице формы Я ее и вызываю в и записываю в сессию.

```
$_SESSION['captcha'] = captcha();
?>
```

Затем вставляю вставочку в нужное место формы

```
<form action="КУда Отсылаешь форму на проверку" method="post">
    <br>
    <input type="text" required='required' title="имя" name="username" placeholder="имя" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="email" required='required' title="почта" name="email" placeholder="ваша почта" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="url" title="HOMEPAGE" name="hompage" placeholder="ваш сайт" />
    <br>
    <br>
   **<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']; ?>**
    <br>
    <input type="text" required='required' title="CAPTCHA" name="captcha" placeholder="captcha" />

<input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
```

---

```
Затем проверка в том файле где будет обрабатываться форма.
    session_start();
    $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];
    if($captcha!== $_SESSION['captcha']){ОТПРАВЛЯЕШЬ ЮЗЕРА НАЗАД К ФОРМЕ)}
```